# Adding picture description on a separate form

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have picture boxes added to a `FlowLayout` panel and a `ContextMenu` strip (associated with picture boxes) with `'Add description'` item.

When I right click on a `PictureBox` and select `'Add description'`, a new form pops with large preview of the picture and a text box to write the description.

How can I preserve the text written by the user on the new form, after it's closed, so if user wants to edit the description, he doesn't have to type it from scratch again?

I figured I'd have to store the description somewhere and load it into the form when user clicks on the same picture again, but how can I know what picture he clicked on?

There is probably a smarter way to go about this, but I can't think of one right now, so I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Can you add a tag on the picture?

Comment: tag property solved it, thank you.

Comment: Good.  I am glad you are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make use of `Tag` property to hold the picture description info.

As for to identify the `PictureBox` on context you can make use of `MouseEnter` event. Basically Define a class level `PictureBox` variable (`PictureBoxOnContext`).

Then you can add a `MouseEnter` event handler to the `PictureBox` instance and cast the `sender` to a `PictureBox` and assign it to the `PictureBoxOnContext` variable.

when you right click on the `PictureBox`, `MouseEnter` is already triggered and the relavant `PictureBox` is selected into the `PictureBoxOnContext` variable.

Then on the 'Add description' context menu click you can check if `PictureBoxOnContext != null` and pass this to the preview form.

(rest you should be able to figure out; probably making use of delegates to pass back the information to parent form)

```
private PictureBox PictureBoxOnContext;

private void AddPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();   
  //Your code logic to add PictureBox to FlowLayout 

  picBox.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(PictueBox_MouseEnter);

}

void PictueBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBoxOnContext = (PictureBox)sender;
}


private void AddDescriptionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PictureBoxOnContext != null)
    {
        //Pass this PictureBoxOnContext to your preview window/ your opearations

    PictureBoxOnContext = null;

    } 
}
```